# How to Step Down a Low Voltage (≤1.0v) DC Signal by a Factor of 0.9 or 50mV Static?

Tags: voltage

Alright you e-lectronic masterminds, I've got a predicament that I'm not quite sure how to solve.  Basically, I need to take a 20mA DC voltage signal that varies between 0.1v and 1.0v several times a second (~20Hz) and step it down EITHER by a factor of 0.9, or by 50mV static.  If you were faced with the same situation, how would you go about doing this?  Ideally, I'd like to get my hands on something that's pre-fabbed.  If I could keep the soldering iron out of it, that'd be great..  Thanks!

**Update:** I must be pretty bad at this. There's like 15 different ways to do this.. Thanks for all your help, friends.. The op amp idea got me thinking.. Would this do the trick?  Is 10kΩ enough for the input on a LM741?

[image]

Comment: R2R op-amp with a gain of 0.9?

Comment: Factor of 0.9 implies Vout = 0.9 * Vin. What does 50 mV static mean? Vout = Vin - 50 mV? Also, what is going to be reading this signal? Is it something with high input impedance like an analog to digital converter (ADC)? Because if so, you could just use a voltage divider.

Comment: My apologies, gents.  For some reason, I haven't been getting reply notifications by email for this question.  I was sure I checked the appropriate box..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would reduce the input voltage by 10% and only load the input with 20K.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjJ4DU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm not sure where the 20mA you cite comes in- presumably current capability. If it's a current loop signal then you could simply shunt the 50 ohm load resistor with a resistor of value 450 ohms and that would be it (parallel resistance 45 ohms, so voltage drop at 20mA 900mV)

Answer (score 0):

[image: quick op amp circuit]

The quick and dirty lm358 circuit shown below will give you a .9volt out for a 1 volt in.